# Extract multiple Words using regex on excel data

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset in Excel:

```
column1                   
 Bank A : 12
 Bank B : 40
 Bank C : 55
```

where it contains only a single row with Bank A, B and C information inside one cell.

How would I be able to use regex in Python to create 3 columns whereby my new dataset is:

```
 Bank A     Bank B      Bank C
  12          40          55
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the following regex:

```
(.*?)\s:\s(\d+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cToW35/4)

Or using this regex to be more forgiving with the spaces before and after the `:`

```
(.*?)(?:\s+)?:(?:\s+)?(\d+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cToW35/3)

Explanation:

```
(.*?)    # For Group 1, match every character
\s:\s    # until reaching a space + : + space
(\d+)    # For Group 2, match every digit
```

Then with your python code you can access contents of Group 1 and 2 using the [Match.group()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) method and build the columns as you need.